# Typescript throws errors in node_modules with strict compiler options

Tags: typescript, node-modules

There are several github issues about why errors in `node_modules` are thrown although that folder is excluded in `tsconfig.json`. If there is any `import` on the lib it is included, ignoring the `exclude` property.

However when using **stricter compiler options** (i.e. `strictNullChecks`, `noUnusedLocals`, ...) and **reference any lib that is not designed to work on those options**, errors are thrown.

Thus whenever using such a lib it is always a **decision of not using the lib or not using the compiler option**. However there are big libraries/frameworks that do not support those options (i.e. Angular) so it seems like there is no way of using those options to ensure strict checks in the own project.

Am I missing some possibility to avoid errors in node_modules being thrown?
If not, is there any technical requirement to apply those rules to all imported libraries or **what is the reasoning behind this behaviour**?

Answer (score 1):

In all my projects setup I have structure where in root I have:

Folders:

- code_folder
- node_modules

Files:

- package.json
- README.md
- tsconfig.json
- tslint.json
- yarn.lock

Then in tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es6"]
    },
    "include": [
        "code_folder/*"
    ]
}
```